# http authentication cache

Tags: http, caching, authentication

I'm implementing http authentication using basic schema for my server.

Sever sends a 401 response to client and then browser will pop up a window asking for credentials. And then browser will send username/passwd in Authorization header.

The question is, when browser opens the link for a second time, Authorization header was included in the request header but there was no pop up window, seems these credentials
were remembered(cached).

any one knows how to control this? what to do if I need user input passwd every time? what to do if I need to set a valid duration for this cache?

Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it manually. Read [here](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/09/08/logging-out-of-http-auth-with-firefox/)